# keras variational loss function scale

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am very new to NN and tensorflow, recently I have been reading up on keras implementation of variational autoencoder, and I found two versions of loss functions:

```
version1:  
    def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
       recon_loss = original_dim * objectives.mse(x, x_decoded_mean)
       kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
       return recon_loss + kl_loss

version2:
        def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
           recon_loss = objectives.mse(x, x_decoded_mean)
           kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.mean(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
           return recon_loss + kl_loss
```

if my understanding is correct, version 1 is a sum of loss and version 2 is mean loss across all samples in the same batch. so does the scale of loss affect learning result? I tried testing them out, and it largely affect my latent variable scale. so why is this and which form of loss function is correct?

update of my question:
if I multiply original_dim with KL loss,

```
def vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean):
    xent_loss = original_dim * objectives.binary_crossentropy(x, x_decoded_mean)
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1) *original_dim
    return xent_loss + kl_loss
```

the latent distribution looks like below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5l0DA.jpg)

and decoded output looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR3at.jpg)

looks the encoder output does not contain any information. I am using mnist dataset, and the example from https://github.com/vvkv/Variational-Auto-Encoders/blob/master/Variational%2BAuto%2BEncoders.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Summing versus averaging the loss for each example in a batch will simply scale all loss terms proportionally. An equivalent change would be adjusting the learning rate. The important thing is that your normal loss magnitude multiplied by your learning rate do not lead to unstable learning.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried to multiply the learning rate with original_dimension for version 2 loss function and the learning results do not make much sense, is it because of the presence of KL loss, which is not related to original_dimension and thus version 1 loss function is preferred?

Comment: Ah, I see now. Only the reconstruction loss term is multipled by ```original_dim```, not the kl_loss. Depending on how large ```original_dim``` is, this would likely skew your training such that only reconstruction loss was used to train essentially (since this loss term is now much bigger).

Comment: so you mean I should multiply original_dim with KL loss as well? I did that the results looks strange, let me update my question with the results